# Stored data not appearing in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, datagridview, android-sqlite

**GridVIew**
I have implemented grid view in my application but it’s showing nothing although it’s not giving any error.

In xml layout I also couldn’t see the grid view.

**Adapter**

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Food> foodsList;

      public FoodListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Food> foodsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.foodsList = foodsList;
    }

    
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
         return foodsList.size();
        }
    
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position){
 return foodsList.get(position);
        }
    
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        private class ViewHolder{
            TextView    Ename,E_des,E_size,E_Price;
            ImageView MyPic;
        }
    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View r= view;
            ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();
    
            if (r==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                r=inflater.inflate(layout,null);
    
                holder.Ename=(TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.Menu_Name);
                holder.E_des=(TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.Description_name);
                holder.E_size=(TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.itemsSize);
                holder.E_Price=(TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.Price);
                holder.MyPic=(ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.my_Imaage);
                r.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder=(ViewHolder) r.getTag();
            }
            Food food=foodsList.get(position);
            holder.Ename.setText(food.getName());
            holder.E_Price.setText(food.getPrice());
            holder.E_size.setText(food.getSize());
            holder.E_des.setText(food.getDescription());
```

> byte [] foodImages=food.getPICs(); Bitmap
> bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImages,0,foodImages.length);
> holder.MyPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
> return r; }
>
> }

**XML CODE**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="721dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:columnWidth="120dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MAIN_ACTIVITY**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpage);
        GridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        list= new ArrayList<>();
        Adapter= new 

FoodListAdapter(Mainpage.this,R.layout.food_items,list);
        GridView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        Cursor cursor=AddMenu.sqLitHelper.GetData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(5);
            String Name=cursor.getString(1);
            String Description=cursor.getString(2);
            String Price=cursor.getString(3);
            String Size=cursor.getString(4);
            byte [] Pics=cursor.getBlob(0);
            list.add(new Food(Pics,Name,Description,Price,Size,id));
        }

        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Could someone help me !!**

Comment: Please post your code so that it will help others to find the mistake in your code.

Comment: Make sure you have given proper height width.

Comment: I have set it to match parent

Comment: //In xml layout I also couldn’t see the grid view. Means you cannot see it in the layout preview in android studio?

Comment: yes its not showing data

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
        Cursor cursor=AddMenu.sqLitHelper.GetData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
   
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(5);
            String Name=cursor.getString(1);
            String Description=cursor.getString(2);
            String Price=cursor.getString(3);
            String Size=cursor.getString(4);
            byte [] Pics=cursor.getBlob(0);
            list.add(new Food(Pics,Name,Description,Price,Size,id));
        }

     FoodListAdapter adapter = new FoodListAdapter(Mainpage.this,R.layout.food_items,list);
        GridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I couldn’t identify any error at there, would you please tell me in details?

Comment: @Azami In your case, you are passing a empty list to the adapter but you have to first add item into the list and then call the setAdapter() method. Follow the way I've stated above.

Comment: Not working as you show me!

Comment: Anyone could help me?             @Sumit Kumar , @ kamal…!

Comment: May be data is not in database that you are fetching. Above code is fine